# Translation of: "How many people are you?"

Tags: translation

Can anyone please tell me the correct Chinese translation of the following sentence:
"How many people are you?"

Comment: It would be "你们有多少(个)人？"

Comment: You're welcome. But this question appears to be off-topic because of the rule "questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated", I hope you can understand why I vote to close it :)

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that, I'm sorry. I did do some research but the only thing I could find was that 你是几个人 was not the right translation. I'll dig a bit deeper next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When entering a restaurant in China you will typically be asked 您几位.

I'm not completely sure if this can be applied to all contexts though. Perhaps someone more proficient than myself can comment on that.